# MYSQL : Connecting to mysql from : 127.0.0.1 + telling ip tables to allow only 127.0.0.1 for mysql port : Logic vs Common Sense

Tags: mysql, iptables, python

if i make 1 billion or 1 trillion queries to MYSQL database..
from 127.0.0.1 via port 3306..

vs..

if i make same amount of queries to MYSQL database also from 127.0.0.1 via port 3306..

but with 1 difference.. in this case i would have this in the iptables..

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

rather than the regular..

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

can there be any speed consequences ? 
can there be any efficiency consequences ?

because the human mind says.. "how can there not be a consequence if it has to  be verified by the iptables that it actually is 127.0.0.1 and not some other IP address that is trying to establish a connection "

Comment: You should allow the `lo` interface

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a measurable performance impact. If you really want to know if this has efficiency consequences: test it.

It's an additional check for every *new* connection but this should be negligible. I don't think you're opening a new connection for every request. If you connect once and send 1 trillion queries to your MySQL DB, there will be only one additional check. Everything else will be part of an already established connection and will therefore be allowed before this rule.

*If* you open a new connection for every query, this should have a higher impact (three-way handshake) than checking for the source IP.